# Sending an image file response - node.js

Tags: image, node.js, sockets, webserver

I need to implement a web server using only net module and socket.write commands.
I'm using the following code for sending text files (html, css and etc):

```
fs.readFile(file,encoding='UTF8', function (err, data) {
if (err) throw err;
var dataToReturn=data.toString();
socket.write('Content-Length:'+dataToReturn.length+'\r\n');
socket.write('\r\n');
socket.write(dataToReturn);
});
```

Its working fine, but it doesn't work when I need to send image files.
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting the encoding to `utf8`, you have explicitly told Node to convert your file into a text string, but it is a binary image so the conversion process will probably corrupt some of the data and make you have the incorrect length. Leave the data as a Buffer like this:

```
fs.readFile(file, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    socket.write('Content-Length: ' + data.length + '\r\n');
    socket.write('\r\n');
    socket.write(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fs.readFile(file, function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  //Content-Length should be binary length not string length
  socket.write('Content-Length:'+data.length+'\r\n');

  socket.write('\r\n');
  socket.write(data);
});
```

You may need a content-type to make your response more valid :)

socket.write('Content-Type:' + mimetype + '\r\n');